# How would I get the sum of squares of two Lists in Scala?

Tags: list, scala

If I have two lists

```
val first = List(1, 2, 3)
val second = List(4, 5, 6)
```

How would I obtain the following?

```
(1-4)^2 + (2-5)^2 + (3-6)^2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

zip, map and sum:

```
first.view.zip(second).map(t => t._1 - t._2).map(x => x*x).sum
```

- *zip* combine elements of the two list into a tuple
- *view* is used to have the list computed lazily to not build a structure between the two map calls

(edit to replace `reduceLeft` by `sum`)

---

After seeing the comments, I feel I had to come back and explain about views. Basically a view turns a `Traversable` into an iterator like structure so that multiple intermediate structures don't have to be created when apply methods like `map`, `zip` and a few others. The type members of [GenIteratableViewLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.GenIterableViewLike) gives a sense of what operations have special processing. So typically if you have a bunch of map, filter, drop, takeWhile applied in sequence, you can use view to gain some performance. The rule of thumb is to apply `view` early to minimize how many intermediate `List` are created and if necessary use `force` at the end to go back to `List` (or whatever collection you're using). Thus Daniel's suggestion.

The thing about performance is that in practice if that's important you sort of have to do a reality check. Here are some numbers (lower is better):

```
no view List(62, 62, 62, 62, 63) sum: 311
view before zip List(32, 31, 15, 16, 31) sum: 125
view after zip List(31, 46, 46, 31, 31) sum: 185
iterator List(16, 16, 16, 16, 15) sum: 79
zipped List(62, 47, 62, 46, 47) sum: 264
```

Code is here:

```
import testing.Benchmark

def lots[T](n: Int, f: => T): T = if (n > 0) { f; lots(n - 1, f) } else f

def bench(n: Int, id: String)(block: => Unit) {
  val times = (new testing.Benchmark { 
    def run() = lots(10000, block)
  }).runBenchmark(n)
  println(id + " " + times + " sum: " + times.sum)
}

val first = List(1, 2, 3)
val second = List(4, 5, 6)

bench(5, "no view") { first.zip(second).map(t => t._1 - t._2).map(x => x*x).sum }
bench(5, "view before zip") { first.view.zip(second).map(t => t._1 - t._2).map(x => x*x).sum }
bench(5, "view after zip") { first.zip(second).view.map(t => t._1 - t._2).map(x => x*x).sum }
bench(5, "iterator") { first.iterator.zip(second.iterator).map(t => t._1 - t._2).map(x => x*x).sum }
bench(5, "zipped") { (first, second).zipped.map((a,b) => a - b).map(x => x*x).sum }
```

Comment: Wouldn't `view` be better before `zip`? Also, another alternative is `zipped`.

Comment: Why would view be better before zip?

Comment: @GKelly, `first.zip(second).view` will create a full list then transform to view, while `first.view.zip(second)` will apply the view optimization one step earlier.

Answer (score 5):

In general you probably want to define a function if it's anything complex, rather than applying multiple maps. You can do this as a helper method, or anonymously in-line.

```
def op(i: Int, j: Int) = { val m = i - j; m * m }

(first, second).zipped.map(op).sum
```

Or

```
(first, second).zipped.map( (i, j) => { val m = i - j; m * m } ).sum
```

`zipped` is a bit more convenient than `zip` in these situations, because it can be mapped to a function taking 2 arguments, rather than a single tuple on which you have to use the `._1` and `._2` fields.

Comment: IMHO it's better readable and more concise to write `(first, second).zipped.map {(x,y) => (x+y)^2}.sum`.

Comment: @bse: `^` is xor in Scala (and Java), not the power.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. Guess I've been doing too much Haskell lately.

Answer (score 2):

with a left fold:

```
(0 /: first.zip (second)) ((a, b) => a + (b._1 - b._2)*(b._1 - b._2))
```

starting with a zip.