# Elegant traversal of a source in Scala

Tags: scala, iterator, traversal

As a data scientist I frequently use the following pattern for data extraction (i.e. DB, file reading and others):

```
val source = open(sourceName)
var item = source.getNextItem()
while(item != null){
    processItem(item)
    item = source.getNextItem()
}
source.close
```

My (current) dream is to wrap this verbosity into a Scala object "SourceTrav" that would allow this elegance:

```
SourceTrav(sourceName).foreach(item => processItem(item))
```

with the same functionality as above, but without running into StackOverflowError, as might happen with the examples in  [Semantics of Scala Traversable, Iterable, Sequence, Stream and View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569489/semantics-of-scala-traversable-iterable-sequence-stream-and-view)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If Scala's standard library (for example `scala.io.Source`) doesn't suit your needs, you can use different `Iterator` or `Stream` companion object methods to wrap manual iterator traversal.

In this case, for example, you can do the following, when you already have an open source:

```
Iterator.continually(source.getNextItem()).takeWhile(_ != null).foreach(processItem)
```

If you also want to add automatic opening and closing of the source, don't forget to add `try`-`finally` or some other flavor of [loan](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Loan) pattern:

```
case class SourceTrav(sourceName: String) {
  def foreach(processItem: Item => Unit): Unit = {
    val source = open(sourceName)
    try {
      Iterator.continually(source.getNextItem()).takeWhile(_ != null).foreach(processItem)
    } finally {
      source.close()
    }
  }
}
```